# QGIS: Join by Location: Option to retain all attributes of spatially related objects of my join layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, concatenation

I am facing the problem that I want to join the attributes from one specific column of ALL intersecting features from my join layer to my target layer in case of an intersection (1:n relationship) using QGIS. I can´t find any option to do so having wasted all week on this problem. I am looking for a strategy, concatenating the desired attributes of my join layer in a column of my target layer.

Do you know if there is any way to do so without having to do too much scripting?

Comment: There are several questions asking similar, for example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149831/how-to-do-a-one-to-many-spatial-join-query-in-qgis   It is not currently possible.