# Getting concatenated attribute values from Spatial Join

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, virtual-layer

How can I query polygon features that intersect other polygon features in QGIS?  I have ZIP code areas and city areas, and I would like to list all the ZIP codes that intersect the city areas. Example: San Antonio= 78209,78258,78259,78250, etc.

[image]

I've been looking for a method for a while that can do this in QGIS, I tried "list unique values and union" commands in the vector tools and no luck.  I know you can do a Union in ArcMap Pro but I don't have that software here. I was also able to do this in GeoMedia Pro years ago. I am unable to figure out in QGIS how to do some polygon vs polygon analysis.

---

I am still having problems with this, I was able to create an intersection layer but I can't figure out how to associate the results back to the city area feature. I would like to add a field to City_Area which would list the ZIP Code names separated by comma. (City_A=78205,78204,78203,78201)

Comment: Check "select by location". Based on your description, you need "intersect" tools not "union".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to create a [Virtual Layer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html) and write some SQL.

[image]

Type the following query into the Query section of the dialog:

```sql
SELECT c.geometry, c.CITY_NAME, group_concat(z.code) AS ZIP_ids
FROM ZIPCODE z, CITY_AREA c 
WHERE ST_Intersects(z.geometry, c.geometry)
GROUP BY c.CITY_NAME;
```

Adjust field names in the query. For example, I assumed ZIP codes are stored in the `code` field of your ZIPCODE layer. Test the query.

Choose proper values for other options such as Geometry column, type, and CRS. Finally, click `OK`.

You should get a new layer with concatenated ZIP ids for each CITY_AREA.

Comment: Thank you and howdy from Texas....it worked perfectly....cheers....and thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

For automization purposes one could also get a combination of city names and ZIP codes by using the Python console (QGIS2.18):

```py
from qgis.utils import *
import csv

CITY_name_list=[]
ZIP_id_list=[]
cities_list=[]
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
    if field.name() == 'CITY_NAME':
        idx_CITY_NAME = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
    if field.name() == 'ZIP_id':
        idx_ZIP_id = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    name=(attrs[idx_CITY_NAME])
    cities_list.append(name)
    ZIP=(attrs[idx_ZIP_id])
cities_set=set(cities_list)
for cities in cities_set:
    CITY_name_list.append(cities)
    ZIP_list=[]
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        attrs = feature.attributes()
        if cities==attrs[idx_CITY_NAME]:
            ZIP=attrs[idx_ZIP_id]
            ZIP_list.append(ZIP)
    ZIP_string=', '.join(ZIP_list)
    ZIP_id_list.append(ZIP_string)

rows=zip(CITY_name_list,ZIP_id_list)
header_list =["CITY_NAME", "ZIP_id"]
with open(r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\cities.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',quotechar=';')
    writer.writerow(header_list)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Simply load the intersected layer into QGIS and change the path where the csv with the city - ZIP combinations will be saved.