# How to transfer attribute values in a One to Many relationship in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

How could one go about recreating this Arcmap workflow and result in QGIS?

https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting concatenated attribute values from Spatial Join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212862/getting-concatenated-attribute-values-from-spatial-join)

Comment: With QGIS 2.99 and aggregation functions with the @parent variable
https://medium.com/@salvatorefiandaca/qgis-3-0-funzioni-di-aggregazione-9c8c389985c5

Comment: Annoying this was closed as @pigreco is correct, this is what I was looking for!