# Buffered one-to-many spatial join QGIS3

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, buffer, spatial-join

I'm trying to spatial join bus stops and census block groups. However, these are a bit tricky with walking distance. Many bus stops are right on the borders of census block groups or within walking distance of others, as shown below.

[image]

I've buffered them 1320 feet (the proper coordinate system is being used) so that each bus stop circle is large enough to touch or cover every census block group that is within walking distance. See below. [image]

I want to figure out how to do a one to many spatial join or the equivalent so that, for each census block group, I have a record of each bus stop inside of it or within walking distance of it. I've tried all sorts of combinations within "Join Attributes by Location" and none seem to work. The bus stop layers have individual stopID's and each census block has a GeoID. I'm trying to either get an output that has each census block that is within or intersecting (I think these are the right terms) a bus stop or vice versa. Maybe something else would work better?

Here are parts of the attribute tables for block groups and bus stops respectively. The lon and lat for bus stops are the original points, but they are buffered. 
[image]
[image]

Update: I tried using field calculator and got this, which still fails.[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149831/how-to-do-a-one-to-many-spatial-join-query-in-qgis ?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what code to use in the Virtual layer. Editing my post now to include parts of the attribute table

Comment: Done! I should mention that I'm self taught and have only been using QGIS for 2 months

Comment: I added in my failed field calculator code

Comment: From the screenshot you are QGIS 3 user. Is it QGIS 3.0.x? Can you use the latest QGIS 3.2? `Join attributes by location` has been remodeled to allow `one-to-many`.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.2 and used one to many but I'm still not seeing the results I'm looking for. Either the joins fail or the attribute table they produce repeat the same census block for each bus stop line or vice versa

Comment: @Roc If you are still interested for an answer - do share a small sample of the data set so that yours truly can suggest a concrete answer (ie tested instead of made-up) via PostGIS/QGIS combo.

Comment: If I understand the auto-translation correctly, this is easier to achieve, as follows: 1) Buffer groups of parcels + Union area of parcel groups themselves; 2) Check which stops fall into the combined polygon (Intersects)...